# Why "onFailure" hook is not providing any output (Laravel Task Scheduler)?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, scheduled-tasks, laravel-10

Using **Laravel 10.9**, I have a controller **TestController** with a method **test** like that :

```
public function test() {
    throw new \Exception('this is an error');
}
```

In **Console\Kernel**, I have a scheduled task like that :

```
$schedule->call(function() {
    $instance = new TestController();
    $instance->test();
})->everyMinute()
  ->onSuccess(function() {
    dd('ok');
})->onFailure(function(\Exception $e) {
    dd('failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
});
```

I know my scheduled task failed because I get **'failed: '** message but why `$e->getMessage()` returns nothing ? It should return **'failed: this is an error'** but it returns just **'failed: '**

Comment: There is nothing in the docs to say that you can pass instance of exception into the onFailure closure?

Comment: @Snapey https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#task-hooks written here "If output is available from your command, you may access it in your after, onSuccess or onFailure hooks by type-hinting an Illuminate\Support\Stringable instance as the $output argument of your hook's closure definition" but also with a Stringable instance it does not work...

Comment: You have to output a string from your task, not an exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a console command instead of a controller class, you can capture the output.

```
php artisan make:command test
```

app\Console\Commands\test.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Test extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Its just a test';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->error('something went wrong');

        return Command::FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Then in the Kernel.php

```
        $schedule->command('test')->everyMinute()
          ->onSuccess(function() {
            dd('ok');
        })->onFailure(function(Stringable $output) {
            dd('failed: ' . $output);
        });
```

This will output "Failed: something went wrong"

Comment: so it works only with a $schedule->command, and not with a $schedule->call ?

Comment: You cannot return an error AND a message from a controller

Comment: I don't want to return an error AND a message from a controller, I want to throw an exception when scheduling a method from a controller (or even from a simple class) and get this exception in "onFailure" method

Comment: Dont use a controller for something that is clearly not a Http request

Comment: Allright, but I just want to use "call" and not "command" to run my scheduled task and get my exception back in "onFailure" method... Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Forget the onFailure method. That is for detecting return codes and console output.  Instead, wrap the `schedule->call` in a regular try-catch block.  Throw an exception in your class and catch it in the kernel.php.

Comment: If onFailure is for detecting return codes and console output, so why does it work with "call" method ? I mean, if my scheduled "call" failed (like in my example), it does run the onFailure because I got 'failed: ' message but without any exception and this is what I can not understand here...

Comment: "A failure indicates that the scheduled Artisan or system command terminated with a non-zero exit code", hero on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/scheduling#task-hooks).